# Pushing objects to array sometimes does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, select

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<select name="region-select" id="regions-select" class="form-control">
    <option selected=""> </option>
    <option value="23">Name1</option>
    <option value="24">Name2</option>
    <option value="25">Name3</option>
    <option value="28">Name4</option>
    <option value="33">Name5</option>
    <option value="35">Name6</option>
    <option value="213">Name7</option>
    <option value="9999">Name8</option>
    <!-- 200 elements... -->
</select>
```

I have the following `JavaScript (jQuery)`:

```
var regions = [];

$("#regions-select > option").each(function() {
    regions.push({
        key:   this.value,
        value: this.text
    });
});

console.log(regions["213"]); // there is no such emelement
console.log(regions["9999"]); // there is no such emelement
```

Almost all elements exist in array. But some of them do not. For example, `regions with key == 213 and 9999`.

Comment: You want to use associative arrays (use `{}` instead of `[]`). To insert values into it, use `regions[this.value] = this.text;`.

Comment: `regions["213"]` implies a key, but you are treating it like an associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an associative array, your array doesn´t have an index of 9999 unless it has over 9998 elements:

```
var regions = {};


$("#regions-select > option").each(function() {
    regions[this.value] = this.text;   
});

console.log(regions["213"]); // Name7
console.log(regions["9999"]); // Name8
```

Comment: your code works fine. But, why my code sometimes works fine too?

Comment: @denis your code works in cases where the object's `key` accidentally happens to match its corresponding `index` within the array.

Comment: @denis your code works as long as the values of the options don´t have any 'jumps', that is to say, they are all continuos. So only then will the array index have the same index as the value

Answer (score 1):

Everything here looks correct. Because regions is an array, it is accessed by an index, not by a key. However you could achieve what you seem to be trying to do with an object instead.

```
var regions = {};

$("#regions-select > option").each(function() {
    regions[this.value] = this.text;
});

console.log(regions["213"]); 
console.log(regions["9999"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
var regions = [];

$("#regions-select > option").each(function(e) {
    regions.push({
        key:   $(e).val(),
        value: $(e).html()
    });
});
```